# How to show jQuery Datatable error in a bootstrap alert-warning div rather than the alert box

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, datatables, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on an ASP.NET Core 2.1 website and I am using [Datatables.net](https://datatables.net/) to display my record lists retrieved from a backend API.

This issue I am trying to resolve is that, whenever an error occurs while retrieving the data from the backend API, I want the error message to appear in a Bootstrap alert-error DIV on the same page as the datatable.

I have looked at https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/30033/override-default-ajax-error-behavior and [Enable datatable warning alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50684951/enable-datatable-warning-alert) but I am not strong in javascript so I am having some difficulty determining how to implement this feature.

Currently, I have the datatable set up in my cshtml page as follows;

```
<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        var table = $("#sitelist").DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "filter": true,
            "orderMulti": false,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Sites/LoadData",
                "type": "POST",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columnDefs": [
                { "orderable": false, "targets": 6 },
                { "className": "text-center", "targets": [4, 5] },
                {
                    "targets": [4, 5],
                    "createdCell": function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
                        if (cellData) {
                            $(td).html('<i class="far fa-check-circle text-primary""></i>');
                        } else {
                            $(td).html('<i class="far fa-times-circle text-danger""></i>');
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "columns": [
                { "data": "Id", "name": "Id", "autoWidth": true, "defaultContent": "" },
                { "data": "SiteName", "name": "SiteName", "autoWidth": true, "defaultContent": "" },
                { "data": "CompanyId", "name": "CompanyId", "autoWidth": true, "defaultContent": "" },
                { "data": "CompanyName", "name": "CompanyName", "autoWidth": true, "defaultContent": "" },
                { "data": "IsAdminSite", "name": "IsAdminSite", "autoWidth": true, "defaultContent": "" },
                { "data": "IsEnabled", "name": "IsEnabled", "autoWidth": true, "defaultContent": "" },
                {
                    "render": function (data, type, full, meta) { return `<a href="/sites/edit?id=${full.Id}"><i class="far fa-edit text-primary" title="Edit"></a>`; }
                }
            ],
            // From StackOverflow http://stackoverflow.com/a/33377633/1988326 - hides pagination if only 1 page
            "preDrawCallback": function (settings) {
                var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(settings);
                var pagination = $(this)
                    .closest('.dataTables_wrapper')
                    .find('.dataTables_paginate');
                pagination.toggle(api.page.info().pages > 1);
            }

        });

    });


</script>
```

And here is the loaddata action in my SitesController class;

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> LoadData()
    {
        try
        {
            await SetCurrentUser();
            ViewData["Role"] = _currentRole;

            var draw = HttpContext.Request.Form["draw"].FirstOrDefault();
            var start = Request.Form["start"].FirstOrDefault();
            var length = Request.Form["length"].FirstOrDefault();
            var sortColumn = Request.Form["columns[" + Request.Form["order[0][column]"].FirstOrDefault() + "][name]"].FirstOrDefault();
            var sortColumnDirection = Request.Form["order[0][dir]"].FirstOrDefault();
            var searchValue = Request.Form["search[value]"].FirstOrDefault();
            var pageSize = length != null ? Convert.ToInt32(length) : 0;
            var skip = start != null ? Convert.ToInt32(start) : 0;
            var request = new SitesGetListRequest
            {
                OrderBy = SetOrderBy(sortColumn, sortColumnDirection),
                Filter = SetFilter(searchValue),
                PageNumber = (skip / pageSize) + 1,
                PageSize = pageSize
            };
            var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var token = tokenSource.Token;

            var endpoint = $"api/companies/{SetCompanyId()}/sites/filtered";
            var siteData = await _client.GetSiteListAsync(request, endpoint, token);
            if (siteData.Sites != null)
            {
                return Json(new
                {
                    draw,
                    recordsFiltered = siteData.Paging.TotalCount,
                    recordsTotal = siteData.Paging.TotalCount,
                    data = siteData.Sites.ToList()
                });
            }
            //TODO: Find a way to pass error to a Bootstrap alert-warning DIV rather than the jQuery (javascript) alert box
            var errorMessage = $"Http Status Code: {siteData.StatusCode} - {siteData.ErrorMessages.FirstOrDefault()}";
            return Json(new
            {
                data = "",
                error = errorMessage
            });

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            const string message = "An exception has occurred trying to get the list of Site records.";
            _logger.LogError(ex, message);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

As it stands right now, If an error exists in the object returned from the API call, I pass a message to the error property in the returned json and it shows up as an javascript alert popup box on my cshtml page and when I click OK, the datatable displays "No records found", as shown in the images below;

[image: Popup Alert on Error]

and...

[image: After popup alert is cleared.]

What I want is for the error message to display in a bootstrap alert-danger div at the top of the cshtml page. I so not want the alert popup to appear and I still want the datatable to show "No records found".

I think that what I am looking for is described on [Enable datatable warning alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50684951/enable-datatable-warning-alert)...

Disable the alert popup by using

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'none';
```

And pass the error message to the BootStrap div using

```
 $('#example')
.on( 'error.dt', function ( e, settings, techNote, message ) {
    console.log( 'An error has been reported by DataTables: ', message );
} )
.DataTable();
```

but instead of

```
console.log( 'An error has been reported by DataTables: ', message );
```

use something like

```
$("#error").html(MY ERROR MESSAGE HERE);
```

and assign id="error" to the bootstrap div.

But, I am having trouble figuring out how to trigger the Ajax call from my loaddata method in the SitesController and also how to correctly add the error event to the beginning of my  datatable script.

Before I burn more time trying to work this out, I thought I would put this on SO and see if anyone with javascrit/jquery experience can provide some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the error property to the ajax call. Probably the best will be to use [fnServerData](https://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnServerData).

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        var table = $("#sitelist").DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "filter": true,
            "orderMulti": false,
            "sAjaxSource": "/Sites/LoadData",
            "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                $.ajax({
                   "dataType": 'json',
                    "type": "GET",
                    "url": sSource,
                    "data": aoData,
                    "cache": false,
                     "success": function (data) {
                          fnCallback(data);                   
                      },
                     "error": function(error){
                        $("#error").html(error);
                     }
                });
             },
            "columnDefs": [
                { "orderable": false, "targets": 6 },
                { "className": "text-center", "targets": [4, 5] },
                {
                    "targets": [4, 5],
                    "createdCell": function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
                        if (cellData) {
                            $(td).html('<i class="far fa-check-circle text-primary""></i>');
                        } else {
                            $(td).html('<i class="far fa-times-circle text-danger""></i>');
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "columns": [
                { "data": "Id", "name": "Id", "autoWidth": true, "defaultContent": "" },
                { "data": "SiteName", "name": "SiteName", "autoWidth": true, "defaultContent": "" },
                { "data": "CompanyId", "name": "CompanyId", "autoWidth": true, "defaultContent": "" },
                { "data": "CompanyName", "name": "CompanyName", "autoWidth": true, "defaultContent": "" },
                { "data": "IsAdminSite", "name": "IsAdminSite", "autoWidth": true, "defaultContent": "" },
                { "data": "IsEnabled", "name": "IsEnabled", "autoWidth": true, "defaultContent": "" },
                {
                    "render": function (data, type, full, meta) { return `<a href="/sites/edit?id=${full.Id}"><i class="far fa-edit text-primary" title="Edit"></a>`; }
                }
            ],
            // From StackOverflow http://stackoverflow.com/a/33377633/1988326 - hides pagination if only 1 page
            "preDrawCallback": function (settings) {
                var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(settings);
                var pagination = $(this)
                    .closest('.dataTables_wrapper')
                    .find('.dataTables_paginate');
                pagination.toggle(api.page.info().pages > 1);
            }

        });

    });


</script>
```

Comment: When I run this code, it hangs in the LoadData method in the SitesController, on the line  

var draw = HttpContext.Request.Form["draw"].FirstOrDefault();  I do not get any exception or visible error. Just the "initializing" text is shown on the datatable in the web page. I am using v1.10.19 of DataTable.Net and the reference you linked refers to v1.9. Could that be the problem?